# What is the difference between UIManager.getDefauts() and UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults()?

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, uimanager

I am trying to override Nimbus LookandFeel values to my Java Swing application.

When I try to set "nimbusSelectionBackground" and "Table.background" values to change using  UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults() like this.

```
UIDefaults jDefaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();

//change nimbusL&F Selection Background color
jDefaults.put("nimbusSelectionBackground", mySelectionBackgroundColor); 

//change Table Background color
jDefaults.put("Table.background", myTableBackgroundColor); 

//update ui trees
for(Window window : Window.getWindows()){
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);
}
```

This works for "Table.background" but It does't work for "nimbusSelectionBackground";

But when I using UIManager.getDefauts() to change defaultFont value like this.

```
UIDefaults jDefaults = UIManager.getDefaults();

//change nimbusL&F Selection Background color
jDefaults.put("nimbusSelectionBackground", mySelectionBackgroundColor); 

//change Table Background color
jDefaults.put("Table.background", myTableBackgroundColor); 

//update ui trees
for(Window window : Window.getWindows()){
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);
}
```

It works perfectly for both of them.

So my question is **Why ?** What is the difference between UIManager.getDefauts() and UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults() ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. Having a look at the code, this is my understanding:

1. `getLookAndFeelDefaults` returns a UIDefaults that is created by `NimbusLookAndFeel` at the initialisation time. Nimbus itself is not monitoring the changes for this table. But UIManager gives a value from this table whenever requested by a component before looking at the one maintained by it. So all standard component UI defaults can be modified by changing this table.
2. `getUIDefaults` returns a UIDefaults that is created by UIManager. This table is monitored by Nimbus (using PropertyChangeListener) and Nimbus updates its internal default values. Nimbus uses these internal values for UI and doesn't refer back to get the values from UIManager.

That said, according to the java doc of `getLookAndFeelDefaults`, we are supposed to be using only `getUIDefaults` and it is consistent with your experience.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you